Webhook error on Twilion when trying to communicate with OpenAI
I'm frustrated here, got stuck, can't overcome this :/
I'm trying ChatGPT but it can't correct it.
Project
My project is to communicate Whatsapp Business with OpenAI using Twilio.
Problem
Twilio is getting the message from whatsapp but can't post on Firebase webhook. It's giving on message details:
Warning 11200 Twilio’s servers were unable to fetch a non-error response from the designated URL.
Request Inspector  URL null
Tried solution
So I tried to run a local server to see what happened.

firebase emulators:start
ngrok http 5000
Twilio webook updated starting with ngrock address (https://ngrok-address/firebase-webhook-address)
Sent a message again to

Errors
On Twilio:
This time Twilio could request to the URL but gave HTTP status 404.
And again the same 11200 warning.
Post request Message Text says:
source Component 14100
http Response 404
ErrorCode 11200
LogLevel ERROR
Msg Not Found
Email Notification false
Response body says "Cannot Post"
On ngrock command window:
15:40:40.875 -03 POST /firebase-webhook-address 404 Not Found
On firebase emulators command window:
!  functions: The following emulators are not running, calls to these services from the Functions emulator will affect production: auth, firestore, database, pubsub, storage, dataconnect
!  functions: Your requested "node" version "22" doesn't match your global version "20". Using node@20 from host.

Code on index.js:
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const twilio = require('twilio');
const { exec } = require('child_process');

// Credenciais diretamente no código
const accountSid = 'XXX';
const authToken = 'XXX';
const twilioPhoneNumber = '+XXX';
const openaiApiKey = 'XXX';

// Inicializar o Firebase Admin SDK apenas uma vez
if (!admin.apps.length) {
    admin.initializeApp();
}

const client = twilio(accountSid, authToken);

const welcomeMessage = "Olá! Como posso ajudar você hoje?";

exports.whatsappWebhook = functions.https.onRequest({ allowUnauthenticated: true }, async (req, res) => {
    const messageBody = req.body.Body;
    const fromNumber = req.body.From;

    try {
        // Verificar se é a primeira mensagem
        const userRef = admin.firestore().collection('users').doc(fromNumber);
        const userDoc = await userRef.get();

        if (!userDoc.exists) {
            // Primeira mensagem
            await userRef.set({ fromNumber: fromNumber });
            await client.messages.create({
                body: welcomeMessage,
                from: `whatsapp:${twilioPhoneNumber}`,
                to: fromNumber,
            });
            res.send('Primeira mensagem enviada.');
        } else {
            // Segunda mensagem em diante
            exec(`python3 main.py "${messageBody}" "${openaiApiKey}"`, async (error, stdout) => {
                if (error) {
                    console.error(`exec error: ${error}`);
                    res.status(500).send('Error processing the request');
                    return;
                }

                const reply = stdout.trim();

                await client.messages.create({
                    body: reply,
                    from: `whatsapp:${twilioPhoneNumber}`,
                    to: fromNumber,
                });

                res.send('Message sent');
            });
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        res.status(500).send('Error processing the request');
    }
});

Code on main.py
import os
import sys
import openai

# Chave da API do OpenAI passada como argumento
openai.api_key = sys.argv[2]

def get_response(prompt):
    response = openai.ChatCompletion.create(
        model="gpt-4",
        messages=[
            {"role": "system", "content": "You are a helpful assistant."},
            {"role": "user", "content": prompt},
        ],
        max_tokens=150,
    )
    return response.choices[0].message["content"].strip()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    prompt = sys.argv[1]
    response = get_response(prompt)
    print(response)

`
Code on package.json
{
    "name": "botgenio",
    "description": "Firebase project",
    "scripts": {
        "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions"
    },
    "engines": {
        "node": "20.x"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "dotenv": "^16.4.5",
        "firebase-admin": "^12.1.1",
        "firebase-functions": "^5.0.1",
        "google-auth-library": "^9.11.0",
        "openai": "^4.51.0",
        "twilio": "^5.1.1"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@eslint/js": "^9.5.0",
        "eslint": "^9.5.0",
        "globals": "^15.6.0"
    }
}

I'd appreciate any help. Thank you,
Best,
André Gabriel.

It sounds like the issue might stem from the Node.js version mismatch. Twilio received a non-error response HTTP status 404, meaning the URL was not found. Your project specifies Node.js version 20, but the emulators are using version 22. Ensure your local environment and Firebase use the same Node.js version by configuring the engines field correctly in your package.json and running install the right version if necessary. This should help Twilio successfully interact with your Firebase webhook. Debug the endpoint to confirm it is reachable and correctly implemented.
